# Hiding Extended program check errors for Includes in ABAP

Tags: abap

How can I stop the ABAP extended program check (SLIN) from reporting errors in include libraries that I may not have write access to?

I like to leave the extended check with as few errors & warnings as possible, usually when I intentionally use something in a way that may cause a warning, I use the pseudo comments ("#EC * etc) to hide the message.  This also tells the next programmer that I at least thought about the possible consequences of using something in a particular way.

When these statements are in includes that I have no control over, I would like to hide the messages without changing the offending libraries/includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **SET EXTENDED CHECK OFF**

```
 SET EXTENDED CHECK OFF.
INCLUDE: zoffendinginclude.
SET EXTENDED CHECK ON.
```

Remember to use **SET EXTENDED CHECK ON** as soon as possible after that.

EDIT:  From ECC6 EHP5 this statement is considered obsolete.  It will still work, but the Extended program check will complain if you use it in conjunction with pragmas.  (Go Irony)